# patching value inside of rows in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

How can i patch the value inside of my row. I have this unit_price that if i selected a specific ingredient in the select option, it would patch it in the input field of the unit_price? Pls see this link for the codes [SEE THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3p6dfu?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
onSelectIngredient(event): void {
    const formData ={
      ingredient_id: event.target.value
    }
    console.log(formData);
    this.patchValues();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following Changes to the `patchValue` method.

```
 patchValues(id,i) {
    let x = (<FormArray>this.addForm.controls['rows']).at(i);
    console.log(x);

    x.patchValue({
      unit_price: this.ingredients[id - 1].price
    });
  }



  onSelectIngredient(event,i): void {
    const formData = {
      ingredient_id: event.target.value
    }
    console.log(formData,i);
    this.patchValues(event.target.value,i);
  }
```

**Template Changes**

```
<select (change)="onSelectIngredient($event,i)" class="form-control" formControlName="ingredient_id"> // to get the row id
```

Working example in [`link`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch)

Comment: Can you explain what this line means? "this.ingredients[id - 1].price". Why do you write "[id - 1]"? Thanks

Comment: because the row count from the template starts from 1 where as our array it starts with 0 this is the reason @Joseph